# Issues when combining debug_backtrace with auto_prepend_file

Tags: php, debug-backtrace

I have a PHP script that will allow me to track which file required it via debug_backtrace().  I wanted to auto prepend *(Via auto_prepend_file within php.ini)* the file so then I could build a log of the frequency in which each PHP script is ran for internal analysis.

It works fine when I create a file that requires it however it causes an error when I "auto_prepend_file" it.  My understanding of auto prepend was that it will require whatever file you identify.  However, the returned array of debug_backtrace appears to be empty when auto-prepending.  Any ideas on what may be happening?

Code example for those curious

first.php

```
<?PHP
require('second.php');
?>
```

second.php

```
<?php 
var_dump(debug_backtrace());
?>
```

For the actual auto prepending I'm just identifying second.php.  When auto prepending I get:

```
array(0) { }
```

When going to first.php within the browser I get:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["file"]=> string(39) "/var/www/first.php" ["line"]=> int(4) ["function"]=> string(7) "require" } }
```

Any and all help is appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this something you could use xdebug for? Anyway, show some code

Comment: Code example added.  I've never used xdebug before, I'll check it out.

Comment: Where is the "auto prepending code"? — please show your logic, for clarity

Comment: I'm specifying "/var/www/second.php" @ auto_prepend_file within php.ini.  Sorry I should have been more specific.  (I added a clarifying statement)

Comment: What is your aim of all this? It sounds like you are trying to brew your own autoloading scheme. Don't do that. Use composer or at least the built-in functionality. For statistics I'm sure you can make use of xdebug or the likes

Comment: So what will you do with the backtrace?

Comment: I inherited a pretty large project that contains a lot of legacy php code.  I just wanted a simple way to track which scripts were actually being used over the course of a month or so in order to do some cleaning.

I initially was going through the access.log but it was spread over a bunch of files and was getting difficult to parse.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103043/discussion-between-michael-and-ron).